# Disallow MPI to run on the headnode

Tags: mpi

I have a Rpi cluster MPI runs perfect on, one issue I am having is that MPI is using the master node as a compute node, how do I configure MPI so it only runs on the compute node. I tried removing the head node's IP address from the file that I use to run with mpirun, but I get back:

```
HYDU_sock_connect (./utils/sock.c:171): unable to get host address for mastern (2)
main (./pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:209): unable to connect to server mastern at port 42525
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Whats your mpirun command look like?

Comment: `mpirun -np 4 -f ip_file mycode.x` @timofiend

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't start up an MPI rank on the node that you launch from, I believe most basic launchers will still start up some sort of daemon process on that node. If that's a problem, you might need to launch from a different node.

Comment: I have used plenty of clusters that don't run on the head node just for execution, by using the same commands. So it may be something with configuring mpi but no luck finding anything yet